# NSNotification for UIAlertController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, user-interface, swift

Is there an option to observe and get the information about appearing and disappearing?
I want to grayscale my elements like apple ui-elements by appearing of UIAlertController!
Since now i found out that the "_UIBackdropViewComputeAndApplySettingsNotification" was called and contains userInfo about the appearing view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is, everything works automatically. You just have to implement..

```
override func tintColorDidChange() {
    self.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

..and of course working with the `tintColor`

Thanks matt for quick answer!

Answer (score 1):

You are going to *make* the UIAlertController's view appear, so how can you *not* know? You don't need to observe it; you're *doing* it (by calling `presentViewController...`).

That takes of what happens when the alert appears. What about when it disappears? Well, it disappears because the user tapped a button. You get to write the handler for every button in the alert. So again, you know when the alert is disappearing, because your handler is running.

Comment: What is apple doing? Are they calling every ui-element in view to grayscale? I want to create a class for everyone they should not need to call a grayscalefunction after releasing the alert - automatically through observing notification would be nice.

Comment: Oh. Well, that didn't seem to be what you were asking. That's a completely different question! You need to learn about the `tintAdjustmentMode`. The runtime simply changes the `tintAdjustmentMode` to make the whole interface behind the alert turn grey (or not grey)

Comment: You might be interested in this example, where I create an interface just like an alert (shadow view, dimmed interface elements): https://github.com/mattneub/custom-alert-view-iOS7/blob/master/CustomAlertViewDemo/CustomAlertViewTransitioner.swift

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the other answers: each of your `UIView` subclasses should implement `tintColorDidChange` to be notified of the change.

Here's a sample implementation:

```
class someLabel : UILabel {
    override func tintColorDidChange() {
        let isInactive = self.tintAdjustmentMode == UIViewTintAdjustmentMode.Dimmed
        if (isInactive) {
            // modify subviews to look disabled
            self.textColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        } else {
            // modify subviews to look enabled
            self.textColor = self.tintColor
        }
    }
}
```

A few other good code samples (albeit in Objective-C) can be found in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19798712/how-do-i-animate-tintcolor-to-gray-on-a-custom-drawn-control-when-a-sheet-alert).